# plotting a t distribution curve over my histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I generated 100 values of B0 and B1 in my regression model `y=B0 + B1*X + error`.

I drawn my histogram for both BO and B1 using `hist(B0)` and `hist(B1)`.

How do I draw the t distribution for both B0 and B1 on their respective histograms?

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/density.html)
Somewhere halfway down the page you will find `# Add a Normal Curve`
This should give you the basic guidance on how to add distributions to a graph.